# Not sure if a gradients bug on Chrome or something wrong in my code

Tags: css, google-chrome, checkbox, linear-gradients

Exactly. What the title says.

I am using the [input-checked hack](http://dabblet.com/gist/319f27a5a1996eb84292) to make a dropdown menu visible when clicking an arrow button. It can then be closed again by clicking a cross button. The "button" is a span inside a label. The html looks like this:

```
    <div>
        <input id="pubs" type="checkbox">
        <label for="pubs" onclick><span></span></label>
        <h3>Pubs</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Since the input/label pair and the dropdown menu **need to be inside the same parent for the hack to work**, and I want to have a background color for the label region and a different color (transparent) for the dropdown menu, I am using a horizontal linear gradient that looks like this:

```
div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(yellow 4em, transparent 4em);
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

where 4em is the height of the visible area. If you open Chrome and copy and paste that code in [this CSS patterns gallery](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#horizontal-stripes), it works. However, it doesn't work when implementing the click & show; the thing appears transparent and only when you click the arrow button the yellow background shows. Check the **[DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/6d19290e52d94b6c5729)**. Open it in FF and then in Chrome to see what I mean.

I'm not sure where the problem is, and I even went crazy with the vendor prefixes in order to make it work, but failed miserably.
Can you reproduce the issue? Does anybody have any idea of what's going wrong? I've run out of ideas.

Cheers!

Comment: I understand the humor behind the picture but does it in any way pertain to the posted problem?

Comment: Man, it's Saturday and I am working. Relax. It does no harm and I have explained my problem precisely, made a demo, include references, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what's a good scenario for this hack?

Comment: @Narong If you don't want to rely on Javascript for critical functionality of your site. Check out "progressive enhancement".

Comment: @Narong If the user's browser doesn't support gradients it will just see a transparent background. If the user has JavaScript disabled, you could still use the dropdown. The only problem is if the user's browser doesn't support :checked, but I think that only happens with IE8 and down... IE8 is showing the ul (at least in my dev tools emulator) IE7 is not. However, I am not too worried about people still using IE7 because they are 0% of my visits. IE8 are 1% of my visits.

Comment: Was just wondering about the drop down hack because most, if not all, popular browsers have JavaScript enabled by default. For the people that disables them, it's probably only temporarily for.. unmentionable net activities. And for people that disables it permanently, they're not feeling like they're missing out if your site depends on it. Pretty sure they're used to it since every other site they visit is static also.

Comment: @Narong Think widely. The less JavaScript you use for things you can achieve with CSS, the better performance your site will have. Even if they have JS enabled, I only use JS for things I can not do with CSS. If something can be done with CSS, don't do it with JS. Compare, for example, the performance of a site that implements parallax with CSS and with JS. CSS is way smoother. Another example: mobile phones. Their system is way slower than a desktop computer, and their internet connection sucks most of the time.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to keep interactivity controlled by JS and Layout/Styling controlled by CSS. It makes it easier to read and maintain in my opinion. Although there are certainly instances where it is reasonable to cross over.

Comment: I totally agree with you about separating interactivity and styling. However, the world is not an idyllic place, and as long as there are so many different scenarios to cover, it's preferable to be responsible as a developer and make things work for everybody in the smoothest possible way.

Comment: @Xirux Nefer, you are absolute right. CSS is much smoother, when it is implemented. However, many "cool things" that you can do in CSS3 have yet to e implemented across all browsers and the hack you are using is no where near as smooth as doing the same in JavaScript. Anyway, if you like hacking things instead of doing it the "conventional" way, then I'm glad you've found a solution. Good day.

Comment: @Narong I am not implementing any "cool thing", I am using a simple CSS selector.The :checked selector is implemented in all browsers and their older versions, except IE8 and down, which in my case is less that 1% of my total visits.So yes, it is smoother than JS.On the other hand, gradients are a "cool thing" that is not yet widely supported, but those who can't see my gradient will see a transparent bg instead, which is OK. Also, you should use the new and updated technologies to push the web forward, otherwise we will still be coding html 4.0. Older browsers will die eventually

Comment: I forgot to add, if a browser can't render some CSS, it will ignore it and continue loading the page without problems. If JS fails, your page may be frozen, broken, doing weird stuff, etc. etc. I am not against JS since I use it daily, but you have to choose the way you implement your stuff wisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the first stop.

Change your gradient from:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(yellow 4em, transparent 4em);
```

To:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(yellow 0, yellow 4em, transparent 4em);
```

Comment: That solved the issue!
I've tried all kind of weird combinations but this solution didn't come to my mind. Thank you!

Comment: Now I'm curious about why the gradient without the first stop worked in the CSS patterns gallery, since both it and my demo page use prefix-free for the vendor prefixes ¿?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why it worked sometimes and not others. Probably worth looking into.

Comment: Looks like it has some problems with the height calculation, since it is changing. If I add an element below the visible part, (first div in the [**updated DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/6d19290e52d94b6c5729)), or if I increase the background size of the div (third div in the updated DEMO) it works without the first stop.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if related, but there is a still a problem with gradients in Chrome, reported over 4 years ago.

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41756